# Provide a PenetrationTesting Report?

Tags: penetration-testing

We have a job for a larger customer where we use Twilio as a bulk sms system and photo shoots from a photo booth system.

now the customer asks if we can Provide a Penetration Testing Report. to request the security of the data we are sending and storage of telephone nr.

the questions are quite short but they want detailed answers.

•   Confirmation from the vendor that the data is encrypted at rest.
•   Provide a Penetration Testing Report from the handler of the phone numbers.
•   Deletion Policy from the handler of the phone numbers.

what can i do to answer these questions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. It'd possibly be on-topic at [security.se] but you should read their help first to be sure

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you work for a consultancy. You have a client who is purchasing a solution from you which includes using Twillo.

I assume that you have a contact within Twillo given that you are using their product as part of your solution. To answer the clients questions you are going to need to reach out to your contact at Twillo and get their help. Here are some more details on the specific questions.

You need to consider the architecture of your solution. Who is storing the numbers at rest. Is it the client based on the deployment of your solution. You based on providing a SaaS solution. Or Twillo based on using their product?

*Confirmation from the vendor that the data is encrypted at rest.*

Assuming that Twillo store the numbers then it this answer should be fairly straight forward to obtain and is often asked of vendors by large companies. There should be no problem with the right person in Twillo answering this question.

*Deletion Policy from the handler of the phone numbers.*

Again, particularly considering the recent changes to data protection laws e.g. GDPR this should be a simple request to Twillo.

*Provide a Penetration Testing Report from the handler of the phone numbers.*

This is the hard one to solve. Unlike the earlier two questions which are standard and companies answer them on a regular basis this is likely not to get answered. Where I have worked in organisations that have provided pen test reports to clients it has been under aggressive NDA's. This could prevent you passing on the details to the client.

In summary, you will need to find the right person in Twillo to ask. A great starting point will be your account manager.